# Usage of radio value in ID selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Given this `html`:

```
<form action="">
    <div id="choices">
        <input type="radio" name="stype" id="opt1" value="input1_div" checked=""/> Opt1
        <input type="radio" name="stype" id="opt2" value="input2_div"/> Opt2
    </div>
    <div id="stypes">
        <div id="input1_div">
            <input type="text" id="input1" name="input1" placeholder="input1"/>
        </div>
        <div id="input2_div" style="display: none;">
            <input type="text" id="input2" name="input2" placeholder="input2" disabled=""/>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="#sbutton">
        <input type="submit" id="input3" value="Submit"/>
    </div>
</form>
```

I use following `jQuery` to hide/disable `input` fields based on selected `radio` buttons:

```
jQuery('#choices input').each(function() {
    var item = this;
    $(this).click(function() {
        if($('input[type=radio][name=stype]').is(':checked')) {
            $('#stypes > div').hide();
            $('#stypes input').not("#sbutton").prop('disabled', true);
            $('#' + $(item).val()).fadeIn();
            $('#' + $(item).val() + ' input').prop('disabled', false);
        }
    });
});
```

All-in-One in this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/83k2fy02/).

I'm particularly unsure about my technique to incorporate `radio value` into the `id selector`:

```
$('#' + $(item).val()).fadeIn();
$('#' + $(item).val() + ' input').prop('disabled', false);
```

What is the correct way to do it? Other tips regarding my `jQuery`?

Comment: why do you need different inputs? couldn't you interpret submitted value based on the selected radio button?

Comment: For presentation only, thus display different inputs for different form variants.    

`Interpret submitted value based on the selected radio button` - in fact this is what I do on the server side. However my question is not about that.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you don't need a sophisticated `jQuery.each` loop to bind the click and to define `this`. In each event handler `this` will be the caller of the function. In your case it is enough to have `click` function for all of them.

As you said in comments, it's only matter of presentation. I prefer to have one field instead of two fields. Even I prefer to have a fixed `name` for this text input, though in order to make it very similar to your example I change the `name` and `placeholder` accordingly.

```js
$(function(){
  $('#choices input').click(function() {
      var newName = $(this).val(),
          newPlaceholder = $(this).attr("data-placeholder");
      $('#interchangable_input[name!='+newName+']').hide()
        .attr("name", newName)
        .attr("placeholder", newPlaceholder)
        .fadeIn();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="">
        <div id="choices">
            <input type="radio" name="stype" id="opt1" data-placeholder="Input one" value="input1" checked=""/> <label for="opt1">Opt1</label>
            <input type="radio" name="stype" id="opt2" data-placeholder="Input two" value="input2"/> <label for="opt2">Opt2</label>
        </div>
        <div id="stypes">
            <input type="text" id="interchangable_input" name="input1" placeholder="Input one"/>
        </div>
        <div id="#sbutton">
            <input type="submit" id="input3" value="Submit"/>
        </div>
    </form>
```

Few more suggestions:

1. You can use `<label for="target id">` for each option label in radio buttons or checkboxes. It will work fine with `click` event handler, even if the user clicks on the label instead of the button itself.
2. You can hid some information as `data-*` attribute in `html5`. You don't need to necessarily use `value`.

### Update for multiple items

In case of group of multiple items in form, I can imagine a form with different sections or pages. The `<fieldset>` can be use to group these items. In *HTML5* you could just disable the fieldset tag by `<fieldset disabled>` when you change the form page with jquery. (With exception of IE browsers). Because of this exception we need to disable all items in subforms. In order to handle this part, I defined a class `.form-element` which applies for all form inputs. You can also use `<div>` instead of `<fieldset>`, then you will need to track their enable/disable status.

```js
$(function(){
  // initialization by disabling form-elements and hiding them
  $("#subforms fieldset[disabled]").hide();
  $("#subforms fieldset[disabled] .form-element").attr('disabled','disabled');

  // choice tracker
  $('#choices input').click(function() {
    var $target = $($(this).attr("data-subform")),
        $oldElement = $("#subforms fieldset:not([disabled])");
    $oldElement.attr('disabled','disabled').hide();
    $oldElement.find(".form-element").attr('disabled','disabled');
    
    $target.removeAttr("disabled");
    $target.find(".form-element").removeAttr("disabled");
    $target.fadeIn();
  });
});
```

```css
fieldset {
  border: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="">
        <div id="choices">
            <input type="radio" name="stype" id="opt1" data-subform="#subform1" value="subform1" checked=""/> <label for="opt1">Opt1</label>
            <input type="radio" name="stype" id="opt2" data-subform="#subform2" value="subform2"/> <label for="opt2">Opt2</label>
        </div>
        <div id="subforms">
          <fieldset id="subform1" >
            <input class="form-element" type="text" name="input1_1" placeholder="Input one"/>
            <input class="form-element" type="text" name="input1_2" placeholder="Input two"/>
          </fieldset>
          <fieldset id="subform2" disabled>
            <input class="form-element" type="text" name="input2_1" placeholder="Input one"/><br />
            <textarea class="form-element" name="input2_2" placeholder="Input two"></textarea><br />
            <input class="form-element" type="checkbox" name="input2_3" id="input2_3" /> <label for="input2_3">check this first</label>
          </fieldset>
        </div>
        <div id="#sbutton">
            <input type="submit" id="input3" value="Submit"/>
        </div>
    </form>
```

Comment: thanks for your interesting input, I guess it also saves a few bytes to download the page, as it renders `input` on demand. What would you suggest for *multiple* fields per `radio` option, because in reality number of fields and form complexity varies per selected option. I provided this simplified `html` just to satisfy my initial question.

Comment: I'll update the answer soon. Maybe in an hour for that case.

Comment: Thanks for the update! But isn't your approach pretty much the same like mine, well regardless the misused `each()` function? I also wrap my `sub-forms` into the `div` blocks, which are initially hidden from the `html` and have input fields disabled. How is your method better than mine? Thanks.

Comment: yes it is very similar. I thought using `fieldset` can make it simpler since you can just disable the fieldset for whole elements inside it. but apparently it won't work in IE. I wanted to add that you can actually load each subform from ajax request, but I guess this will do the trick.

Comment: You can manipulate form elements with jquery (similar to my first answer) but it takes more design time for compacted forms comparing to this method.

Comment: I imagined it as a long form with different sections (which most of them are disabled), then jquery helps to simplify the representation by hiding the disabled parts.